# When enlarging a filtration makes a stochastic processes into a solution to an SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, filtrations, stochastic-filtering

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $(Y_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a stochastic process defined on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in [0,1]},\mathbb{P})$.  Suppose also that $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. $(Y_t)_t$ has continuous paths.

When does there exist a stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ defines on some filtered probability space $(\Omega',\mathcal{G},(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t\in [0,1]},\mathbb{Q})$
taking values in some $\mathbb{R}^N$ such that, on $(\Omega\times \Omega',\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{G},(\sigma(\mathcal{F}_s\otimes \mathcal{G}_s)_{0\leq s\leq t})_{t\in [0,1]},\mathbb{P}\otimes\mathbb{Q})$, $(X,Y)_t$ is a strong solution to some SDE:
$$
d(X_t,Y_t)_t = \mu(t,X_t,Y_t)dt + \Sigma(t,X_t,Y_t)dW_t;
$$
where $(W_t)$ is a Brownian motion on $(\mathcal{G}_t)_t$ and $\mu$, $\sigma$ are uniformly Lipschitz.

---

I imagine by taking $N$ very large and putting enough information into $(X_t)_t$ this can always be done?